# Is there any way to read data from the django admin interface request for pre save validation?

Tags: python, django, validation, django-models, django-admin

I know the following function can be used to do some pre-save processing. But, how can I access the request data, for example a text field value from the request for doing validation?

```
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # do something for validation 
        obj.save()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The raw request data is stored in `request.POST`, as it usually is. It's probably better to access `form.cleaned_data`, as Django has already validated it.

However, the `save_model` method probably isn't the correct place to do validation. If you raise a `ValidationError`, then the exception will not be caught and the user will get a 500 server error page. The `save_model` method is more appropriate when you know the data is already valid, for example to set the object's author based on `request.user` before saving.

If you want to do custom validation, a better approach would be to define a model form, and use it in your model admin with the [`ModelAdmin.form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form) setting.

Comment: thnx Alasdair! I've came across the same kind of solutions from other sources.

Answer (score 0):

[Custom form validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#using-validation-in-practice)

This also helped me lot!